# regarding JSP set property

Tags: jsp

I have written the following code:

#### Animal.java

```
package com.MyPack;

public class Animal 
{
    private String name;

    /* getter and setter methods */
}
```

#### Zoo.java

```
package com.MyPack;

public class Zoo 
{   
    private String address;
    private Animal animal;

    /* Getter and Setter Method */
}
```

#### JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="animal" class="com.MyPack.Animal" scope="request">
            <jsp:setProperty name="animal" property="name" value="Tiger" />
        </jsp:useBean>

        <jsp:useBean id="zoo" class="com.MyPack.Zoo" scope="request">
            <jsp:setProperty name="zoo" property="address" value="Bannerghatta" />
            <jsp:setProperty name="zoo" property="animal" value="${animal}" />
        </jsp:useBean>

        <jsp:getProperty name="zoo" property="${zoo.address}" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using EL to print address and I am trying to print name from animal class using `${zoo.animal.name}` however its causing an error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code:

```
<jsp:getProperty name="zoo" property="${zoo.address}" />
```

Should be:

```
<jsp:getProperty name="zoo" property="address" />
```

Also I don't see where have you written the EL `${zoo.animal.name}` in the JSP, also the error-stack trace would be helpful.

#### Edit

You can't use `EL`s in the attribute `property="${zoo.address}"` it does not evaluate expressions, since it requires the actual name of the property inside the `Zoo` class. Moreover even if it evaluated `property="${zoo.address}"` it would have the attribute property as `property="Bannerghatta"`.

So my suggestion is to either use `EL` to display the address as (`${zoo.address}`) or use standard actions to display the address as `<jsp:getProperty name="zoo" property="address" />`, you can't mix both.

I would strongly suggest to go through the following tutorials to get a good grasp of the concept of `EL` and JSP standard actions:

1. [JSP and Java Beans](http://pdf.coreservlets.com/JSP-and-JavaBeans.pdf)
2. [JSP Expresssion Language aka JSP EL](http://pdf.coreservlets.com/JSP-EL.pdf)

Comment: This is the error H whic i am gettingTTP                                Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.ZooAnimal_jsp

Comment: and if i am using "${zoo.animal.name}" in jsp:getProperty like this
<jsp:getProperty name="zoo" property="${zoo.animal.name}" />

its throwing error like this:-
HTTP Status 500 - Cannot find any information on property '${zoo.animal.name}' in a bean of type 'com.MyPack.Zoo'

Comment: @user728907 Please see my edited answer. Also you can update your question with the full stack-trace of the first error `HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.ZooAnimal_jsp`, so that it is visible to more people who can help you better.